# Unattended Installation ubuntu server 20.4 failure after installaion

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, system-installation

I am trying to create an unattended installation with UEFI and a LVM partition, but I am getting an error after the installation finishes.

Here is the error:

[image: screenshot of the error]

And here is the preseed file:

```
# Unmount drives with active partitions. Without this command all the installation process would stop and require confirmation to unmount drives that are already mounted.
d-i preseed/early_command string umount /media || true
# Don't install recommended items
d-i preseed base-installer/install-recommends boolean false
# Install only security updates automatically
d-i preseed pkgsel/update-policy select unattended-upgrades For additional Preseed configuration options, refer to official Ubuntu [installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/.../installatio.../armhf/apbs01.html).
d-i preseed/early_command string umount /media || true
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string main
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-md/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-basicmethods/method_only boolean false
### GPT
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/default_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/default_label string gpt
d-i partman/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman/default_label string gpt
### EFI
d-i partman-efi/non_efi_system boolean true
### Grub
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string         \
  boot-root ::                                \
    1 1 1 free                                \
      $bios_boot{ }                           \
      method{ biosgrub }                      \
    .                                         \
    200 200 200 fat32                         \
      $primary{ }                             \
      $iflabel{ gpt }                         \
      $reusemethod{ }                         \
      method{ efi } format{ }                 \
      mountpoint{ /boot/efi }                 \
    .                                         \
    512 512 512 ext4                          \
      $primary{ }                             \
      $bootable{ }                            \
      method{ format } format{ }              \
      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
      mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
    .                                         \
    1024 102400000 1000000000 ext4            \
      $lvmok{ }                               \
      method{ format } format{ }              \
      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
      mountpoint{ / }                         \
      lv_name{ root }                         \
    .                                         \
   999% 999% 999% linux-swap                 \
      $lvmok{ }                               \
      method{ swap } format{ }                \
      lv_name{ swap }                         \
    .
d-i base-installer/install-recommends boolean true
d-i base-installer/kernel/image string linux-generic
```

The problem happens only on psychical machine installation.

Can someone assist me?

Comment: I don't see an error, just an image of an fsck report.

Comment: ok so why it stuk on this message what can I do to solve it ?

Comment: From the message, it looks like the fsck finished, it got stuck on the next step.   Or maybe the previous steps, which you didn't show.  There are kernel command line options to tell systemd to show more detail about what it is doing that would help.